# Find all prime numbers $p$ such that $(p-2)!$ is not divisible by $(p - 1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all prime numbers $p$ such that $(p-2)!$ is not divisible by $(p - 1)$.

Immediately we see that the statement does not hold for $p = 3$ as
$(3 - 2)! = 1! = 1$ is not divisible by $3 - 1 = 2$ and holds for $p = 2$ as
$(2 - 2)! = 0! = 1$ is divisible by $2 - 1 = 1$.

I tried to apply Wilson's Theorem here, however it works modulo $p$ and it's not clear how to deduce anything related to the divisibility by $p - 1$ from it:

Assumin that the statement holds for a prime $p$:

$$ (p-2)! = (p-1)k, k \in Z $$

$$ (p-1)! \equiv (p-1)^2k \mod p $$

$$ -1 \equiv k \mod p $$

Thus, for example, we know that $k = np - 1$, however $(p-2)! = (p-1)(np - 1)$ is where I run out of ideas.

Comment: Have you tried any examples? That's a crucial part of just about everything in number theory.  In this case, I think trying examples reveals the (probable) answer very rapidly...and then you can try to prove it (not hard in this instance).

Comment: Let $q=p-2$ , then : Query : When is $q!$ not divisible by $q+1$ ? Answer : When $q+1$ is Prime. Query : Can we have $q+1$ & $q+2$ Prime ? Answer : XXXX !

Comment: @Prem  This isn't quite true.  $3!$ is not divisible by $4$, for example.

Comment: Yes , that was why I put a Comment , not a Complete Answer , @lulu , it goes half-way !

Comment: @lulu thank you, I tried and got [3, 5], actually it was not enough for me to made it through until I read Prem's hint, probably I have to get more practice in number theory, but I will remember your general advice for good!

Comment: @Prem thank you, I had to check the proof of the auxiliary statement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997274/is-there-a-quick-way-of-finding-if-n-1-is-divisible-by-n and finally put all the pieces together~!

Answer (score 1):

It can be shown that  there exist infinitely many prime $p>5$ such that for a natural number like $n<p$ , number $(n-1)!+1$ is divisible by p. Let  $n=p-1$ we have:

$(p-2)!\equiv -1\bmod p=kp-1$

which is not divisible by $p-1$

In fact $n=p-a$ and $a=1$ is a very partichlar case.

Note: this is from a problem in book number theory by Sierpinsky.

Comment: I believe it is whether $(p-2)!$ divisible by $p-1$, where $p$ is the prime. [Nothing seems to have been asked about divisibility by $p$ itself]

Answer (score 1):

Render $(p-2)!=1×2×3×...×(p-2)$. If both $2$ and $(p-1)/2$ are among the factors and are distinct, then $(p-1)|(p-2)!$.

That condition is satisfied if $p-2\ge2$, $2(p-2)\ge p-1$, and $(p-1)/2>2$. All these conditions apply for all $p\ge6$. So only $p=2,3,5$ remain in scope. The reader can try these cases.

> This is one property of primes where the exceptional cases are $3$ and $5$, not $2$.